# The surface has been released when I try to setDisplay to MediaPlayer

Tags: android, surfaceview, android-mediaplayer

My xml file:

```
<SurfaceView
    android:id="@+id/surfaceView"
    android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="300dp" />
```

My function to setDisplay:

```
public void playVideo() {
    MediaPlayer mp = new MediaPlayer();
    SurfaceView sv = (SurfaceView) this.findViewById(R.id.surfaceView);
    try {
        mp.setDataSource("sdcard/test/a.3gp");
        SurfaceHolder sh = sv.getHolder();
        mp.setDisplay(sh);***----the exception occured here***
        mp.prepare();
        mp.start();
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (SecurityException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

the log as below:

```
04-24 22:19:33.645: W/System.err(16106): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The surface has been released
04-24 22:19:33.645: W/System.err(16106):    at android.media.MediaPlayer._setVideoSurface(Native Method)
04-24 22:19:33.645: W/System.err(16106):    at android.media.MediaPlayer.setDisplay(MediaPlayer.java:698)
```

I have found some similar questions here, but all of those are not suit for me. Waiting for your answers. Thanks very much.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The Surface can be destroyed. That's why you need to add to the a `public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder)` to your SurfaceView's implementation like this:

> ```
>   @Override
> public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
>     synchronized (this) {
>         hasActiveHolder = false;
>
>         synchronized(this)          {
>               this.notifyAll(); 
>         }
>     } 
> }
> ```

You should also add a function that handles Surface creation:

> ```
> @Override
> public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
>      synchronized (this) {
>         hasActiveHolder = true;
>         this.notifyAll()
>      }
> }
> ```

And modify your own function this way:

```
    mp.setDataSource("sdcard/test/a.3gp");
    SurfaceHolder sh = sv.getHolder();
    synchronized (this) {
       while (!hasActiveHolder) {
              try {
                  this.wait();
              } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                //Print something
              }
        }
        mp.setDisplay(sh);
        mp.prepare();
    }
```

You have another option which is the way Google suggests you use SurfaceView: in a separate thread.

Comment: I have tried what you say, but it doesn't work, and the hold screen turn black. Waiting for your more information. Thank you very much for your answer.

Comment: I just noticed that in surfaceDestroyed I put a synchronized within a synchronyzed block of the same object. Remove the second one. It seems like you are stuck in waiting. I suggest that if this doesn't work, you attach a debugger and pause all threads you see in order to find which thread is in wait()

Comment: I have tried another way to fix it.I move 'setDisplay' to the Callback when the surface been Created('surfaceCreated').It done. Thank you very much for your answer!

Answer (score 11):

It's something related to the sequence of executing, as the surface has to be created first before setting display for the `MediaPlayer`, so you have to override the callback method `surfaceCreated` to the following:

```
@Override
public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    mp.setDisplay(sh); // now "mp" is defined as a class variable
}
```

and now there is no need to setDisplay inside your play method:

```
private MediaPlayer mp; // to use it inside surfaceCreated callback method
public void playVideo() {
    mp = new MediaPlayer();
    SurfaceView sv = (SurfaceView) this.findViewById(R.id.surfaceView);
    try {
        mp.setDataSource("sdcard/test/a.3gp");
        SurfaceHolder sh = sv.getHolder();
        mp.prepare();
        mp.start();
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (SecurityException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Make use of SurfaceHolder.Callback as below

```
SurfaceView mSurfaceView = (SurfaceView) findViewById(R.id.surfaceView);
SurfaceHolder holder = mSurfaceView.getHolder();
final MediaPlayer player = new MediaPlayer();

holder.addCallback(new SurfaceHolder.Callback() {
    @Override
    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        player.setDisplay(holder);
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width, 
    int height) {

    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {

    }
});

String UrlPath="android.resource://"+getActivity().getPackageName()+"/"+R.raw.your_file_name_without_extension;
try {
    player.setDataSource(getActivity(),Uri.parse(UrlPath));
    player.prepareAsync();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
player.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {

    @Override
    public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
        mp.start();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 3):

The simplest way is just to call `setDisplay` in `surfaceCreated`:

```
@Override
public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    mp.setDisplay(holder)
}
```

and don't forget to unbind surface:

```
@Override
public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    mp.setDisplay(null);
}
```

**Note: media player should be initialized somewhere before, for example in `onCreate`.**

Answer (score 1):

For those still having issues, try implementing **SurfaceHolder.Callback** in your activity/fragment/etc and at the **onCreate/onCreateView** method, call the **addCallback(SurfaceHolder.Callback callback)** method, using your activity/fragment/etc as the parameter callback.

Answer (score 0):

We can look at VideoView source code:

```
SurfaceHolder.Callback mSHCallback = new SurfaceHolder.Callback(){
...
    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder)
    {
        mSurfaceHolder = holder;
        openVideo();
    }
    private void openVideo() {
        ...
        mMediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
        mMediaPlayer.setDisplay(mSurfaceHolder);
    }
}
```

So we can learn that we should use `mediaplayer.setDisplay()` in `surfaceCreate` method be called.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I covered sh.unlockCanvasAndPost with

```
if(sh.getSurface().isValid()){
    sh.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);
}
```

And it seems like recognise case when surface is released. If we will check isValid() source will see:

*Returns true if this object holds a valid surface.
@return True if it holds a physical surface, so lockCanvas() will succeed.Otherwise returns false.*